# Jquery datatable how to get parent data from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `jquery` datatable of something like this

[image]

when i click the plus icon, it will show 2 buttons the capabilities and reimbursement, what I want is when i click the capabilities button, I want to get the parent row which are name, all and etc. Is that possible? I tried several method but it doesn't work.

What I tried is

```
    function set_credentials(el) {
        var tr = $(el).closest('tr').parents('tr'); 
        var prevtr = tr.prev('tr')[0]; 
        console.log(prevtr)
```

But i get the html dom.
[image]
I think I almost got it but i need some help. Thanks

Comment: why the image wont show? I added image for illustration

Comment: I don't see the ```set Capabilities``` button in the html. Can you provide this?

Comment: its in the image sir. you can see it? because i cant when i posted the question

Comment: I don't see any ```button``` element in the HTML pictures you provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: the html i posted is the result of `console.log(prevtr)` and i think it does not include the button since it is a child row?

Comment: Is the button inside ```the td class="details-control"```? Why don't you show the HTML of the button ?

Comment: yes sir @ikhvjs

Comment: how can i get the data `mws_name` sir @ikhvjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I console.log(name) for the result.

**Example below**

```js
$("#example").on("click", set_credentials);

function set_credentials(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    var tr = $(event.target).closest("tr");
    var prevtr = tr.prev();
    var name = prevtr.find("td.mws_name").text();
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table id="example">
        <thead>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>button</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="mws_name">joe</td>
            <td>2011-1-1</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><button>set</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="mws_name">Sam</td>
            <td>2011-5-1</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><button>set</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @draw134, no worries. I am happy to help!